# Multiple Counts with single query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mongo Db and would appreciate some help with this query. I have been sifting through posts here for the past couple of days tearing my hair to see if I could find anything related to my query but with no luck.

I have a collection with documents similar in structure to below :

```
_id: xyz
Movieid: 123
MovieName: Titanic
ReleaseDate: 2000-01-01

_id: uvw
Movieid: 456
MovieName: Titanic II
ReleaseDate: 2018-01-01

_id: pqr
Movieid: 789
MovieName: Titanic III
ReleaseDate:
```

I would like to achieve the output as counts for totalmovies, movies with release date, and movies without release date in 3 seperate columns as below:

```
Total   |   Released  |     UnReleased
 3      |       2     |          1
```

I was able to write individual queries to execute the counts, but I am unable to successfully consolidate all that into a single query. The end goal is to create one view producing these counts as output. I have tried using operators such as $and, but can't seem to get the query to work as desired....this is as far as I got :

```
db.getCollection("Movies").aggregate({
  "$and": [
    { "$match": { "ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true } }},
    { "$count": "Total" },
    { "$match": { "ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true, "$nin": [""] } }},
    { "$count": "Released" },
    { "$match": { "ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true, "$in": [""] } }},
    { "$count": "Unreleased" }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can try below [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation

[**`$count`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) aggregation will always give you the counts for only single matching ([**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)) condition. So you need to further divide your each count into multiple section and that's what the [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) provides by processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "Total": [
      { "$match" : { "ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true }}},
      { "$count": "Total" },
    ],
    "Released": [
      { "$match" : {"ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true, "$nin": [""] }}},
      { "$count": "Released" }
    ],
    "Unreleased": [
      { "$match" : {"ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true, "$in": [""] }}},
      { "$count": "Unreleased" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Total": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Total.Total", 0] },
    "Released": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Released.Released", 0] },
    "Unreleased": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Unreleased.Unreleased", 0] }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FugO6dcAVnR)

```
[{
    "Total": 3,
    "Released": 2,
    "Unreleased": 1
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony. This solved my problem. Didn't know about the $facet operator. I just had to make a minor change to the above code. I replaced db.collection.find with db.collection.aggregate because it was throwing me an error, probably due to $facet being an aggregation operator ? Greatly appreciate the help :)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet im getting an error from mongo `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$facet'`

Comment: @NithinChandran What is your mongodb version? Because `$facet` has been introduced in mongodb 3.2 and above.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet My mongodb version is below 3.4. I got the reason meanwhile why it not working

Comment: Great idea, never thought of dealing with this task in such way. Just a tiny question, why are you using '$project' in the end? what's the purpose of it? And another question, is there a limitation of how the number of matches I can look for in a single query?

Comment: @LiorMagen Answer to your first question... I have posted the link in the ouput if you can see. You can remove the `$project` and [see](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ry0OU5JW83i) what happens. `$facet` will give you the nested fields for the counts for each pipeline. For the second question I will edit my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly, Where multiple match conditions not worked in Aggregate.

Comment: @Ashh - Once we do $facet we cant expose other fields right.

Comment: @Hacker No. You can get all the fields inside the `$facet`. If you `$project` limited fields inside `$facet` then you cannot get them in the next stage. Now if you have more question then please ask a question.

Comment: @Ashh - I have posted a proper question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217603/get-2-field-count-for-further-calculation-using-mongo-query

Comment: NB: The $facet stage, and its sub-pipelines, cannot make use of indexes, even if its sub-pipelines use $match or if $facet is the first stage in the pipeline. The $facet stage will always perform a COLLSCAN during execution.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#index-use

Comment: @TreeAndLeaf I know buds... It is just play around aggregation

Comment: @Ashh how can I set a default 0 value to it?
https://mongoplayground.net/p/fKIJfm_VUUx
in this case, I want to show Unreleased as 0 instead of not showing it

Answer (score 4):

You can use below aggregation.

[`$gt > null`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) - to check whether field exists or not in aggregation expressions.

[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to output 0 and 1 based on release date filter.

[`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) to add both released and unreleased count to output total.

```
db.Movies.aggregate([
 {"$group":{
   "_id":null,
   "Unreleased":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$and":[{"$gt":["$ReleaseDate",null]},{"$ne":["$ReleaseDate",""]}]},0,1]}},
   "Released":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$and":[{"$gt":["$ReleaseDate",null]},{"$ne":["$ReleaseDate",""]}]},1,0]}}
 }},
 {"$addFields":{"Total":{"$add":["$Unreleased","$Released"]}}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you Veeram. I tried the above query, however I am getting 0 as the output count for Unreleased. And ideally we would like to avoid adding the released and unreleased to get the total since we may have documents which fall outside of these two scenarios. Appreciate the effort though. Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome. You can add another entry in group stage for Total.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.Movies.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                Total: {
                    $sum: 1
                },
                docs: {
                    $push: '$$ROOT'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                Total: 1,
                Released: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$docs",
                        as: "doc",
                        cond: {
                            $ne: ["$$doc.ReleaseDate", ""]
                        }
                    }
                },
                Unreleased: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$docs",
                        as: "doc",
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$doc.ReleaseDate", ""]
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                Total: 1,
                Released: {
                    $size: '$Released'
                },
                UnReleased: {
                    $size: '$Unreleased'
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it has helped me. Question, how would you return the document data also ?