# Multiple count queries in a single mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to do multiple count queries on the same collection with 3 different conditions at the same time.

```
Date <= x
Date <= y
Date <= z
```

Right now, I do:

```
collection.count(query1, function() {
   collection.count(query2, function() {
     collection.count(query3, function() {
```

Is there a way I can do all 3 queries in a single mongodb query.

Answer (score 2):

Use facet in mongo 3.4 version:

```
db.col.aggregate(
{"$facet":{
  "count1":[{"$match":query1},{"$count":"count"}],
  "count2":[{"$match":query2},{"$count":"count"}],
  "count3":[{"$match":query3},{"$count":"count"}]
}})
```

Comment: hmm.. thank you so much. I am afraid I am on 2.x as of now.

Comment: You are welcome. You can use $group stage to calculate the count as noted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52088969/2683814) for 2.x

Comment: AWS Document DB (docdb/ddb) does not yet support $facet despite 3.6 API.  Soooo... hope I help another to not beat head against wall.