# get 2 field count for further calculation using mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I have below 2 colection

```
**aggregate collection**
{
    _id: '1',
    test_name: 'test1',
    status: "flaked"
    test_ids: [1, 2]
}
{
    _id: '2',
    test_name: 'test1',
    status: "Flaked"
    test_ids: [3, 4]
}

**test collection**
{
    _id: 1,
    run_id: 1,
    test_name: 'test1',
    status: "fail"
    pipeline: "A"
}
{
    _id: 2,
    run_id: 2
    test_name: 'test1',
    status: "pass",
    pipeline: "A"
}
{
    _id: 3,
    run_id: 3
    test_name: 'test1',
    status: "Infra",
    pipeline: "B"
}
{
    _id: 4,
    run_id: 4
    status: "pass",
    test_name: 'test1',
    pipeline: "B"
}
```

I am trying to % of how many times the test flaked like No of Flakes/ no of runs. Above should give me (1/4). 
Test is considered flake only when aggregate result is flaked and one of test is failed. Can this be built with one query.

Comment: What do you mean by `flaked`?

Comment: Result is Flaked.

Comment: Could you be more clear with your question? Also post the output you want