# mongodb - How to get two counts from one query without putting them in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a comments collection with two fields -  "up" and "down". Right now, I use only one of them to get the count using query below:

```
              $lookup: {
            from: "votesComments",
            as: "commentVotes",
            let: {
              commentI: "$_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$commentId",
                      "$$commentI"
                    ]
                  },
                  }
                },
                {
                  "$group" : {_id:"$up", count:{$sum:1}}
                },
                
              ]
            }                

          },
```

The result is:

```
0: {_id: 1, count: 2}  ====>  id = 1 is when "up" field has 1. Total up votes is 2
1: {_id: 0, count: 1}  ====>  id = 0 is when "up" field has 0. Total down votes is 1
```

This is an array. When I unwind it, I only get

```
{_id: 1, count: 2}
```

I need to do one of the following:

1. Get the results in a simple format - `{upvotes: 2, downvotes: 1}`
   OR
2. Unwind the result to include both `[0]` and `[1]` elements of the resulting array.
   OR
3. Is it possible to perform two counts in one query? [Count number of 1s in Up and number of 1s in Down fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Counts with single query in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088666/multiple-counts-with-single-query-in-mongodb)

Comment: @frozen Not really. I posted the answer and its nothing like your link.

Answer (score 0):

This did it

```
            "$group": {
              "_id": "null",      
              "upCount": { "$sum": "$up" },
              "downCount": { "$sum": "$down" } 
            },
```